# Whats the best way to render a 360 video in blender?

Tags: rendering

So I made a 360 degree video in blender but the quality is terrible.
Does anyone know how to make my video look more HD?

Comment: Coud you show your current settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrible in what way? You probably need to up the resolution? For 360 you need at least 4096x2048 if you are rendering equirectangular. Problem with this resolution is that it takes forever to render an animation, so a lot of optimization will be necessary to keep your render times in check.

Comment: I wonder if it'd be faster if we rendered 4 sides and then merged them into one, this way we can have it better optimized since only one side is being rendered at a time instead of loading whole scene at once